# PDFBox: How to create a new page and position text after the current page is full

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

```
//for writing filenames           
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Vorlagen/Analyze/ReportTemplate.pdf"));
PDPage curFileNamePage = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
doc.addPage(curFileNamePage);

contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, curFileNamePage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, 12);
contentStream.beginText();
float curYVal = 650f;
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(20, curYVal);

for (int idx = 0; idx < 377; idx++) {
    if (curYVal - 15f > 0) {
        curYVal = curYVal - 15f;
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, curYVal);
        contentStream.showText("" + idx);
    } else {
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close(); // close writing area
        curFileNamePage = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        doc.addPage(curFileNamePage);

        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, curFileNamePage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, 12);
        contentStream.beginText();
        curYVal = 650f;
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, curYVal);
        contentStream.showText("" + idx);
            }

}
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close(); // close writing area

doc.save("C:\\Users\\noname\\Desktop\\765.pdf");//Saving the document
doc.close();
```

So I have a number of indexes (in this case 377) . My aim is to create a pdf where the indexes gets printed out one after another. (in this case it should go 15f down the y-axis). If the end of the page was reached it should create a new page and start from the beginning.

Now as you would guess the code does not behave as it should. After I execute the code the pdf file gets created with 9 pages but the funny part is each page contains only one number (except first page). The number are: `43,87,131,175,219,263,307,351`.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what the output should look like:

[image]

This is my current output:
[image]

Comment: Elaborate the question more by attaching screenshots of what is expected and what you are getting

Comment: @NiranjanKumar ok wait a little bit

Comment: @NiranjanKumar i've added pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first (not the second)

```
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, curYVal);
```

to

```
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -15f);
```

Because this is a relative position. So the large value makes sense only the first time in a text segment (when it is relative to 0,0). After it is positioned the first time, just substract the offset.